# react-query and placeholder data from a partial query key match, dataset?

Tags: react-query

So, I have a situation like so:

1. get an id that is returned initially on page load. lets say "id=9"
2. I useQuery with it, and get a result.
3. return looks like this:

---

```
queryKey is: ['guest', 9]
//return is
{
  age: 2222,
  year: 2019
}
```

4. I have a third party script that I have to download to get another "id". That sometimes takes a few seconds.
5. I useQuery with that "new" id and get results, now it looks like this.

```
queryKey is: ['guest', 27]
{
  age: 2222,
  year: 2019
}
```

Now, when that second "id" comes thru, the returned data from the useQuery is {}, effectively empty. So, my components gets the intial payload, shows... THEN flashes off, then the "new id" comes thru and re-shows with some verbage in the component that changes.

So, I have two questions.

1. How can I seed my "second useQuery" with the changed id, with the "seed data or placeholder or initialData" from the 'previous' id's call... this way, there is no flash?

I know you can do like the docs show, but I do get at that "previous" id reference?
Or would I have to just take the last one that has the partial "guest" queryKey?

```
 placeholderData: () => {
   return queryClient
     .getQueryData(['guest', ?????])
      ?????
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keepPreviousData: true` option is what you are looking for.

Also see [the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/paginated-queries#better-paginated-queries-with-keeppreviousdata). Even though the docs explicitly mention pagination, all that flag does is make sure that when the query key changes (like with a different id in your case), instead of going to a loading state, you will get the data from the previous query key, the query will stay in success state, and additionally, you'll have an `isPreviousData: true` flag set on the result so that you know it's the previous data.

Comment: cool, its "keepPreviousData", but yeah, that worked. awesome, thanks.

Comment: yes, that's what I wrote. The option is `keepPreviousData`, and on the result object, you'll have `isPreviousData`  :)

Comment: that's what I get for speed reading----- lol, ;-) , thanks again.